# Why do Flash games freeze when I use Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, flash-player

When I play Facebook Flash games with Chrome then they tend to freeze, but when I use Firefox then they don't! Can anyone give me some pointers on how to go about resolving the problem?

Comment: Hi Andy! Your question is a little vague. Could you please tell us which operating system you're using, and which versions of the browsers? What about your Flash plugin, have you updated that as well?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Chrome is always having issues with Flash and I have suggested this answer a few times now, it may not be the correct solution but you can give it a go!

You could try typing in the search bar at the top `chrome://plugins` and then press the +details button in the top right.

If you see that Chrome is using 2 Flash plug-ins then disable 1, preferably the one that says 'pepflashplayer.dll' and just use the stand alone flash plug-in stored on your computer.

Otherwise if there is just the PepperFlash plug-in present then maybe try and download the Flash stand alone player and use that one instead. (Again by going in to `chrome://plugins`  section and disabling PepperFlash)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -2):

This problem happens due to chrome's built-in `Flash Player` which comes `pre-installed with your chrome`.

The built in flash player adds a new process known as `rundll32.exe`.

Google Chrome automatically initiates it and the starting up of rundll32 is what causes the crashes in Chrome.

A temporary solution is to terminate this process and continue working on Chrome. You will not lose any of your tabs. But this problem will arise the next time you wish to start your Chrome browser.

If you are looking for an permanent solution disable Chrome's built-in Flash Player and installed a new one.

Comment: How do you know the OP is on Windows? `rundll32.exe` is certainly not added by Flash Player, it's essential for any Windows system.

Comment: rundll32 could be anything! don't terminate it unless you're really sure of WHAT THAT specific rundll is doing!!!! I don't know how the chrome flash player plugin works, it's possible that it uses a native dll call (via rundll)

Comment: Both the description of rundll32.exe and advice about blindly terminating it are ridiculous.

Comment: @Ravi - You have no idea what you are saying, anyone who follows your advice, would be a fool.  You do understand `rundll32.exe` has nothing to do with Chrome directly right?